# How to define own function in view in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, google-maps-api-3, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to define my own function in Sencha Touch 2 and I'm still getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: function22 is not defined

And my file responsible for this is: Position.js in View directory

```
Ext.define('GS.view.Position', {
extend: 'Ext.Map',

xtype: 'map',

config: {
    title: 'Position',
    iconCls: 'time',
    useCurrentLocation:true,
    mapOptions: {
        zoom: 19
    },

    listeners: {
        maprender : function(comp, map){
            //new google.maps.LatLng,
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(this._geo.getLatitude(), this._geo.getLongitude()),
                title: '1',
                map: map
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function22);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.266064,15.562048),
                title: '1',
                map: map
            });
        }
    }
},
function22: function(){
    alert('some alert');
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sencha touch is only Javascript! Everything that is true for Javascript will work with sencha touch too!

This is how did solve this problem:

In html, before inserting any other javascript, I write this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var MYGLOBALOBJECT={v:{},f:{}};</script>
```

`MYGLOBALOBJECT` is an aray with 2 items, named v and f. `MYGLOBALOBJECT.v` is a hash where I can store all my variables like this:

```
MYGLOBALOBJECT.v.myNumber = 123.45;
MYGLOBALOBJECT.v.justASrting = 'this is a string';
```

Since in Javascript functions are just another type of variable, you can also store funktions in this global object, this is what I use `MYGLOBALOBJECT.f` for:

```
MYGLOBALOBJECT.f.aGlobalFunction = function (parameter) {
    // do something useful
};
```

You can use this function everywhere in your code like this:

```
var xy = MYGLOBALOBJECT.f.aGlobalFunction(someValue);
```

Since `MYGLOBALOBJECT` i defines outside any curly bracket, it is a global object, and you can use it whereever you want.